# The component is used in the template but importing it would create a cycle

Tags: angular

I have two components that reference each other because it is supposed to be recursive. However since Angular 13 I am not able to use it anymore and I get the error stated in the title.

Component A (field.component.html):

```
<app-appendable-fields-group *ngIf="field && field.type === 'appendableFieldsGroup'"  [field]="field" [group]="group">{{field.label}}</app-appendable-fields-group>
```

Component B (appendable-fields-group.component.html):

```
<app-field *ngFor="let fieldOfGroup of groupOfFields" [field]="fieldOfGroup" [group]="group.controls[field.id + '_child'].controls[i]"></app-field>
```

The code is stripped down a little to zoom in on the actual issue. How am I supposed to keep the recursiveness while fixing the error code?

To give some insight on what it does. There is a form with fields. Within the fields there is a field type that is appendable. The appendable field allows more fields to be added including itself thus becoming recursive.

Answer (score 0):

From the angular documentation:

> So when building libraries using the "compilationMode": "partial" setting, any component that would require a cyclic import will cause this NG3003 compiler error to be raised.

The only option that I see is for you to set `compilationMode` to `full`. That will generate a fully AOT-compiled code.

Comment: I already tried that but unfortunately since it is an angular library (sorry that I failed to mention that) that option is also not possible. When I try to publish it to npm it would say: `ERROR: Trying to publish a package that has been compiled by Ivy in full compilation mode. This is not allowed. Please delete and rebuild the package with Ivy partial compilation mode, before attempting to publish.'`